# How to use If-else condition in Selenium (Java) to make the condition in else block work

Tags: selenium

I am trying to find an element in the else block, if the condition in the if block doesn't work.

```
  try
    {
       if(Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Tpay_success']")).isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("Payment is successful");
            Reporter.log("Payment is successful");
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            {
            if(Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("pay_decline")).isEnabled()) 
             {
                System.out.println("pay declined");
                action.moveToElement(By.id("pay_decline")).isEnabled()).click().perform();
                Reporter.log("PAYMENT DECLINED!!");
              }

         }  
    catch(ExceptionInInitializerError ex)
    {
            System.out.println(ex);
    }
  }
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='Tpay_succes']"}
```

I want the else block to be executed if the if block doesn't get executed. 
Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: code hard to read, considering format/indentation (eventually part of the problem, which we don't know). Example brackets same line  after `else` and **in front of `if`**

Comment: @KorayTugay I edited it

Comment: "I want to the else block to be executed if the if block doesn't get executed. " That's exactly how if...else works.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice and its not working.

Comment: still not correct, bracket at end of second  `if`, and in general closing is not matching opening, neither is indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Tpay_success']")).isDisplayed())
```

This doesn't work the way you think it does. `findElement()` will throw an error if the element is not present in the DOM of the currently loaded page. This means that `isDisplayed()` will not be called in such a case.

You can do what you want with a `try...catch`:

```
  try
    {
       Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Tpay_success']"))
       System.out.println("Payment is successful");
       Reporter.log("Payment is successful");
    } catch(ExceptionInInitializerError ex) {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if(Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("pay_decline")).isEnabled()) {
                System.out.println("pay declined");
                action.moveToElement(By.id("pay_decline")).isEnabled()).click().perform();
                Reporter.log("PAYMENT DECLINED!!");
            }
    }
```

Note that you should learn about how to make the selenium driver wait for a specific element rather than using `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Another issue that I'm facing is that, by the time it's reaching the catch block, its getting too late, meaning the submit button with the div id='Tpay_success', in the catch block, is getting lost, when it's reaching it. Is there a way of making it faster, I have removed the Thread.sleep() method.

Comment: is this *kind* of indentation and use of brackets really used with selenium? opening/closing sometimes on extra line, sometimes on same line; opening not matching closing neither indentation??? that's so confusing

Comment: The indentation doesn't matter that much in Selenium but since I'm using with Java, that's the reason the brackets are needed.

Comment: nor does it matter in Java, but it is essential for easy reading/understanding (almost any programing language) - and I doubt that in Selenium you dont need to match opening and closing bracket; e.g. opening on end of `if`, closing on same indent level as `catch` (which by itself is not being closed)

Comment: Yes Selenium doesn't need anything like that, and I have rectified.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger This indentation in this answer is a hybrid between copy/paste from the OP and my editing, including the erroneous missing closing bracket.